Inverse kinematics not working as expected with a chain length greater than two with pole target
I'm trying to make animations featuring a stick figure, I got the idea to have its limbs in the rubber hose style like those seen in old cartoons where the limbs of characters bend in unnatural ways. So I replaced one of the two segmented arms with a singular segment with many subdivisions (Both for the mesh and skeleton.) And I found the arm wouldn't bend if I gave it a pole target. But I want it's "elbow" to point towards the target but instead the hole arm points towards and past the hand bone but if I take off the pole it bends the way i expect it too but does not have the direction for its "elbow" to point.
With pole target:

Without pole target:


Hello, I'm not sure to understand, for such an arm, maybe use only 2 bones but segment them (in the Bone panel > Bendy Bones > Segment)

@moonboots Thanks it works, you could post it as the answer

For such an arm, use only 2 bones but segment them (in Edit mode, go into the Bone panel > Bendy Bones > Segment):


